# Is it possible to factor out $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ from $A + BAB^T - AB^T - BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are symmetric matrices. Is it possible to factor out the matrix $A$ from $$A + BAB^T - AB^T - BA?$$

Note that $B$ is not orthonormal, i.e., $BB^T \neq I$.

In this case, I don't think it's possible to factor out $A$, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not?

$$
A+BAB^T-AB^T-BA=B(AB^T-A)-(AB^T-A)=(B-I)A(B^T-I)
$$